# Use radio buttons for input in formula

Tags: java, android

I want to use radio buttons input in my formula for calculation purposes. I have created one radio group with two radio buttons (12 hours and 24 hours) in it. If a user selects the 12-hour button then I want my "num" (variable) divided by 12, and if the user selects 24-hour button then "num" should be divided by 24. I want to code this in button.OnClickListener.

Questions:
Which data type (e.g. float, int, etc.) or anything else should I use?
How do I save user input in a variable to use it for calculation?

Only Java code is needed.
Radio Button: `onRadioButtonClicked(view: View)` is used.

Comment: edit your post with the code you have so far; show us exactly what is giving you trouble. then maybe someone can help. please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please also show a minimum of effort in researching the topic you would like help with it. It took me 2 seconds to google android radio button and come up with a bunch of examples. see this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton